# Replace model data when there is same product id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi fellow programmers,

I am stuck in this small problem which has been bugging me for the past 2 days. In my project there is 2 modals, product and special_price. What i am trying to achieve to is replace the price for all available product if there is an entry of the product_id in the special_prices table. Hence, my model file is as below:

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :special_prices, dependent: :destroy

  before_save   :upcase_stock_code

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :stock_code, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :status, presence: true, length: { maximum: 10 }
  validates :default_price, presence: true
end
```

special_price.rb

```
class SpecialPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :customer

  validates :product_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:customer_id] }
  validates :customer_id, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true
end
```

my customer controller as where the prices will be shown on the show action is as:

```
def show
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @customer_active = Customer.find_by(id: params[:id], status: "active")
  @user = User.find_by(params[:user_id])
  @special_price = SpecialPrice.find_by(customer_id: params[:id])
  @special_prices = SpecialPrice.where(customer_id: params[:id])
  @products = Product.all
end
```

in my views

show.html.erb

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="prices">
  <h1>Products</h1>
    <div>
      <%= render 'special_prices/price' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

_price.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |k| %>
  <span>
    <%= k.id %>
    <%= k.name %>

    <% if k.id == @special_price.product_id %>
      <%= @special_price.price %>
    <% else %>
      <%= k.default_price %>
    <% end %>
  </span></br>
<% end %>
```

By using the codes above, i am only able to get 1 product to show its special_price. But when i add other entry of special prices of different products_id the array would not update itself. I have done some research and i think it might have something to do with local variable and instance variable, can anyone point me to the right direction? thanks a lot! i'd appreciate any advise.

Comment: did you successfully manage to update the `Product's :special_prices` if new `special_prices` is added to the existing product?

Comment: yes. it does successfully update but only 1 product's :special_prices even if there are 2 or more special_prices for this customer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion: change `_price.html.erb`

```
<% @products.each do |k| %>
  <span>
    <%= k.id %>
    <%= k.name %>

    <!-- show product special_prices -->
    <% if !k.special_prices.empty? %>
      <%= k.special_prices.each do |p| %>
         <span><%= p.price %></span>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= k.default_price %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

since Product `has_many :special_prices` you can call a product special prices by calling `product.special_prices` and that will return a collection of special prices for that certain product.

Comment: Thanks!! this went well for me i just needed to reverse the if end statement. Again thanks for helping!! You saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: oh yea, just realized should be `unless` or !. glad it solve your problem